# Worldgaurd not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

In my main world where the spawn is, regions are working with worldgaurd. I made another  world for warps with mutliverse and when I try to do regions in that world it won't work. I have no current regions set in the world now that I made. No even "pvp deny" will work.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, update your world edit to latest ver, world gaurd also. And if you can to the latest build that your in(if needed).